# File.createTempFile() always makes exception

Tags: java

```
     try {
            final URL url = new URL(surl);


            File createTempFile = File.createTempFile("Download Test 
        File", ".stl");

            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, createTempFile);

            System.out.println("  Download check file lenght 
        "+createTempFile  );

            if (createTempFile.length() == 0) {

                fail(" Downloaded file is empty");
            }

        } catch (final IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            fail("resource has invalid url");
```

Can someone tell me why I get exception for File.createFile here. The exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://xx.xx.com/uploads/xxx/

Comment: Could you post a stack trace?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete exception that you're getting, including the stack trace. I suspect you're getting the exception on the `copyURLToFile()` line rather than the `createTempFile()` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that a file called "http://xx.xx.com/xx" doesn't exist on your hard drive.

Comment: @muktoshuvro if my answer solved your issue, please mark it as correct ;)